# Not able to validate email domain via REGEX in shell

Tags: shell-script, shell, regular-expression

The regex works fine in [Regex](https://regexr.com/6aufd) site.

But the same does not work when using it inside shell.

```
#!/bin/bash

authEmail="nagendra.ks@test.com"
echo "$authEmail"

if [[ "$authEmail" =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?(test)\.com$ ]]; then
  echo "Proper Email detected $authEmail"
else
  echo "Email address $authEmail is invalid."
fi
```

it always print `Email address nagendra.ks@test.com is invalid.`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash's `=~` uses POSIX Extended Regular Expressions (ERE), but you seem to be using [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) syntax. Specifically, the `(?: )` non-capturing syntax isn't supported by ERE. You either need to pass this on to a tool that understands PCRE, such as GNU `grep`, or change the regular expression.

1. Use GNU `grep`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   authEmail="nagendra.ks@test.com"
   echo "$authEmail"

   if printf '%s\n' "$authEmail" | grep -qP '^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?(test)\.com$'; then
     echo "Proper Email detected $authEmail"
   else
     echo "Email address $authEmail is invalid."
   fi
   ```
2. Change the regex

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   authEmail="nagendra.ks@test.com"
   echo "$authEmail"

   if [[ "$authEmail" =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?test\.com$ ]]; then
     echo "Proper Email detected $authEmail"
   else
     echo "Email address $authEmail is invalid."
   fi
   ```

Of course, you don't actually need non-capturing groups. Or capturing groups, for that matter, so you can change the PCRE expression as well to:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?test\.com$
```

Comment: +1.   You can also use perl and perl's [Regexp::Common::Email::Address](https://metacpan.org/release/Regexp-Common-Email-Address) library module.  It will match any valid RFC-2822 email address.

Comment: please fix the grep solution to `printf '%s' "$input" | tr $'\n' ' ' | grep -q -E '^...$'`. i use `tr $'\n' ' '` to replace every newline with an illegal character. here i assume that space is an illegal character. see also [Check if a string matches a regex in Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112707/check-if-a-string-matches-a-regex-in-bash-script)

Comment: @milahu that doesn't seem remotely useful in this case. There are no newlines (and you don't need `$'\n'` for `tr`, a simple `'\n'` should work), and anyway newlines are at leas as illegal as spaces! And then your would only match things exactly 3 characters long from start to finish: not helpful here. Did you maybe mean to comment on another question?

Answer (score 1):

"*Am I missing something?*" unfortunately yes you are. Email addresses are really difficult to validate correctly using an RE. See [How can I validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/2344631) on StackOverflow, which offers this PCRE for [RFC 5322](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt) compliance:

> (?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])

You can use it yourself with `grep -Po`.

The safest way to validate an email address is to send a message to it, and require the recipient either to click a link or enter the token (word, number, phrase) you've included.

Comment: In this case though, the OP seems to need to validate a specific group of emails (note the string _test.com_ that they are explicitly looking for, so it doesn't seem that they would need to validate all possible correct emails, but only those that fit a specific pattern.

Comment: If they only wanted to validate the one in the example code there would be no point validating it. I'd assumed this was a MWE for a generalised case. If we just need to validate `{known_pattern}@test.com` then it's a considerably easier task

Comment: Yes, but because they are explicitly looking for things that end with `test.com`, presumably they are only validating emails in a specific domain even if that is not the domain `test.com` itself. If the question is actually "how can I check that an email is a valid email" and not "how can I check that an email matches this pattern" then all bets are off and doing it in the shell is really not a good idea.

Comment: I'd check that it matched `@test.com$` first. If it is, *then* check if it's a valid email address.